# Mongdb $inc by variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

```
      Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {


        user.cheat = "(Member)"
        user.cost = 1000;
        user.money = 0;
        user.rate = 0;
        user.spy = 200;
        user.adv = 10; 
        user.power = 25;
        return user;

  })
```

I'm using meteor with mongodb.
I'm trying to $inc a database thingy with a var

I have a line that is:

```
click: function () {    
Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$inc: {'money': 'power'  }});
},
```

Nothing happens
I have all the vars defined but I can't seem to be able to increment a var by a var? Maybe wrong syntax?

This on the other hand works:

```
click: function () {    
Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$inc: {'money': 25  }});
},
```

Comment: You can't refer to the value of another field in any update operator.

Comment: This is not possible in a single query. You need to use 2 queries - one to get the value of the other variable, and another to incriment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User **another field** in any **update operato**r.

```
    var variable2 = 1;
   click: function () {    
    Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, 
      {$inc: {'money': this.power },$inc: {'power': variable2 } });
    },
```

**Or** if you don't want increament power then use below one

```
   var variable2 = 1;
   click: function () {    
 Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, 
            {$inc: {'money': this.power } });
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote `'power'`! But also you have to fetch the value of power first.

```
click: function () {    
  var power = Meteor.user().power;
  Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$inc: {'money': power  }});
},
```